# Can you use Fey-Step (Eladrin) while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, eladrin

I've created a Eladrin Druid (using *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*) for a new campaign. However, we've hit one little snag. Eladrin have the Fey Step racial trait built into their kit. Druids have their Wild Shape ability, part of which states:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class,
>   race or other source, and can use them if the new form is physically
>   capable of doing so. (PHB p. 67)

My question being, can a brown bear (for instance) utilize Fey Step while in beast form, or is this breaking some sort of game ruling?

Comment: Can you add a game-and-version tag to this question? I think this is D&D 5th edition, but we require the tag to be sure, so we don't accidentally answer for the wrong game.

Comment: No worries, this if my first forum post. Sorry for the terrible post format.

Comment: Thank-you all so much for your quick & detailed responses. Such an awesome community :).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Should be viable

[Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/classes#WildShape) allows for to:

> ...retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. However, you can’t use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

[Fey Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mtof/elves#ElfSubraces) (From the official release of the Eladrin subrace of Elves in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes) is a racial feature and does not seem to be generated by a physical feature.

> As a bonus action, you can magically teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see. Once you use this trait, you can’t do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

### Physical basis?

Whether or not the Eladrin trait to Misty Step is something inherent or a physical aspect of their being is not clarified (like darkvision), but it is reasonable to allow this interaction as there doesn't seem to be a specific physical association with the Fey Step, it's just part of their abilities (like [Halfling Luck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/halfling#Subrace)).

#### Confusion from Example Subrace from the DMG

The DMG, under Part 3 (Master of Rules) includes a section on Creating New Character Options (page 186.) In this section, they provide some examples to help guide a DM in homebrewing - but these are not official subclasses. In this section, they provide an Eladrin (as well as Aasimar) with different rules than the final published official Subclass options for those races, but do note that these are only example to help guide homebrew on how to create a subrace and not an official subrace for player use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79111/discussion-on-answer-by-nautarch-can-you-use-fey-step-eladrin-while-in-wild-sh).

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR - Using Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, you can use Fey Step while wild shaped. If you don't have access to this sourcebook (or your DM doesn't allow it), you can't­.

---

If you do have access to Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, **you can use Fey Step while transformed**.

In the ToF (p.62), Fey Step is described as requiring only a bonus action to activate.

> **Fey Step**. As a bonus action, you can magically teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see. Once you use this trait, you can't do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

According to the PHB (p.67), a wild shaped druid can neither talk nor cast spells, but can otherwise **use all it's racial and class features**, unless physically unable to in his new form. As "using a bonus action" is not prohibited by wild shape, a ToF Eladrin druid should be able to use Fey Step while under the effect of wild shape.

---

If you do not have access to Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, however, **you cannot use Fey Step while transformed**.

Outside of the ToF, the only mention of the Eladrin subrace is in the DMG, where it is used as an example of a subrace that could be created by a DM. While the ToF should take precedence over the optional variant rules found in the DMG, not all tables will have access to the ToF, or even allow it. In this context, and only in this context, should the rules found in the DMG prevail.

According to the variant rules found in the DMG (p.286), the Eladrin "Fey Step" racial powers allow them to **cast** the misty step spell, which requires a verbal component.

Once again, according to the PHB (p.67), **a wild shaped druid can neither talk nor cast spells**. So while you do retain the Fey Step racial feature, you cannot use it when using the DMG's version of the Eladrin.

The only exception to this is if you are an 18th level druid with the "Beast Spells" class feature, which allows you to cast spells while transformed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79095/discussion-between-nautarch-and-dungarth).

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by 'access' to the ToF. Clearly, the asker had access to ToF at some point otherwise he'd not know about the ToF version of Eladrin. Since that much is clear, the only other thing I can think of you could mean by 'access' is that they have to physically carry a copy of the sourcebook with them at all times or their character becomes invalid? Not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: @Cubic the question originally made no mention of the ToF, which then required 2 possible scenarios. Also, not all groups own/allow all books, so it makes sense to keep the ToF-less section for other readers that have the same question, but not the same books, as the OP. Also, by "access", I mean "access". Because the book exists doesn't mean it's allowed at your table, or that at least one person will have a copy somewhere that's accessible during play in case a rule is questioned. Many groups have a "only use books we own" policy to make it simpler on the DM to keep track of stuff.